# Labeling points in order in a plot 

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two vectors representing the location of points (x,y) that I'd like to plot.

I know how to plot them, but I'd also like to label them 1, 2, 3, 4... with labels visible on the plot.  The labels represent their order in the vector.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
p = rand(10,2);
labels = cellstr( num2str([1:10]') );  %' # labels correspond to their order

plot(p(:,1), p(:,2), 'rx')
text(p(:,1), p(:,2), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
                             'HorizontalAlignment','right')
```

[image]

Comment: I find it's useful to add `'Parent',axesHandle` as additional option to `text`, especially if you're plotting from within a function, to make sure the text actually appears on the right figure.

Comment: Hello, How would you do that with "set" ?  `h=text(p(:,1), p(:,2), labels);
                   
set(h,'Position',[p(:,1) p(:,2)],'String',labels);` It doesn't work.

Comment: @k4lls: That's because `h` is an array of handle graphics (each "label" created is a separate `text` instance). Either you set each `h(i)` in a loop, or you use the special syntax: `set(h, {'Position'},num2cell(p,2), {'String'},labels)`. Learn more about it in the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html#f67-575595