# Display number of elements on histogram bars - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram

Is there a way to display the number of elements on each bar of an histogram in MATLAB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Labeling points in order in a plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140312/labeling-points-in-order-in-a-plot)

Comment: but this is about points. I want to display the number of elements of each bar on top of the bar.

Comment: The top of each bar is also a 2D point.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of [Labeling points in order in a plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140312/labeling-points-in-order-in-a-plot), as labelling a histogram plot with `text` is a lot more of a hassle than labelling a scatter plot.

Comment: text command worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the toolbar of MATLAB plots, including a histogram plot, there's a button called `Data Cursor` (it looks like a blue curve with a black cross and a yellow table). Click this, and then select a bar in the histogram - it will add an explanatory label to the bar, including information about the bin count of the bar. You can pick this label up and drag it to other bars, or add additional labels to other bars.

Comment: This works, but the label can not be placed in the center of the bar, only at the corners of the square

Comment: Really? For me, the label is placed in the exact centre of the top of whichever bar I select.

Comment: can you send me the code of "edit text update Function"?
You will find it by right clicking on a point

Comment: Sure. `function output_txt = myfunction(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)]};

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];
end`

Comment: Yes, same for me, but at my histogram, it displays a box with the coordinates, not in the center