# plotting text from string vector or table on the point plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, text, scatter-plot

I have plotted through `gscatter` in MATLAB. The plot of speed against year. Now there is another column vector or table in my case which contains corresponding strings of the plotted points. That table is `int` variable.

I want to show the corresponding text from that `int` variable of the plotted points on the graph. Can anyone help me?

Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/avqwk5g5ntrxol1/Data_Serial.xlsx?dl=0) to my data.

Here is my code:

```
T = readtable('Data_Serial.xlsx');

int = T.Int;
BW = T.Band;
type = T.Type;
year = T.Year;
g = {type};

labels = cellstr(int); 

% Plot Data
f = figure;
box on;
gscatter(year,BW,g,'rkgb','o*',8,'on','Year','Speed')
hold on;
text(year(:,1), BW(:,2), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
                         'HorizontalAlignment','right')
```

It shows following error:

```
>> Data_Serial
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Data_Serial (line 16)
text(year(:,1), BW(:,2), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Labeling points in order in a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140312/labeling-points-in-order-in-a-plot)

Comment: @gehbiszumeis thanks for your answer. That example I saw. In that example they converted row numbers to string using `labels = cellstr( num2str([1:10]') );`. In my case, I have string table stored in `int`. So I put as  `labels = cellstr(int);` i am using `scatter` function which enables me to plot according to another variable. But that label still doesn't work. I have updated the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should start indexing from 1 in BW.

This should display the plot with text labels

```
text(year(:,1), BW(:,1), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
                         'HorizontalAlignment','right')
```